# Helm - how can I use custom values file in subchart, when installing parent chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

### Issue

Let's say I have a chart `example` and a sub chart `example-sub` .
`values.extra.yaml` are custom values for  `example-sub`.

*File structure:*

```
example
 |-.helmignore
 |-templates
 | |-deployment.yaml
 |-charts
 | |-example-sub
 | | |-values.extra.yaml
 | | |-.helmignore
 | | |-templates
 | | | |-deployment.yaml
 | | |-charts
 | | |-values.yaml
 | | |-Chart.yaml
 |-values.yaml
 |-Chart.yaml
```

Then  `values.extra.yaml` cannot be used when installing the parent chart `example`

### Recreate issue:

`example/charts/example-sub/templates/deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ $.Values.name }}
  custom: {{ $.Values.custom }}
```

`example/charts/example-sub/values.extra.yaml`:

```
custom: my-custom
```

When installing the chart , `custom` value is missing:

```
$ helm template --debug example . -f charts/example-sub/values.extra.yaml 
install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: ""

---
# Source: example/charts/example-sub/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-sub-deploy
  custom:
---
# Source: example/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-deploy
```

While when installing the subchart, it works:

```
helm template --debug example-sub charts/example-sub -f charts/example-sub/values.extra.yaml
install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: ""

---
# Source: example-sub/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-sub-deploy
  custom: my-custom
```

### Question

How can I install the chart `example` including its subchart `example-sub` with the custom values file `values.extra.yaml?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [official documentation of Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#overriding-values-from-a-parent-chart) you will need to create a section in your parent chart named exactly as the sub-chart and inside provide the custom values.

For example:

```
example
|- charts
| |-example-sub
```

your values file under `./example/values.yaml` should be:

```
example-sub:
  custom: my-custom
```

following this example, you can also set values via the CLI with `--set example-sub.custom=my-custom`

Comment: Thanks @totem, I tried the solution - it seems to break the concept that the subchart is independent, because `helm template --debug example-sub charts/example-sub -f charts/example-sub/values.extra.yaml` fails to load the values..

Comment: Actually for me this scenario works. `helm template ./charts/sub-sample -f ./charts/sub-sample/custom-values.yaml`. maybe there's another issue? which version of helm are you using?

Comment: This is not the solution. The subchart can be an independent, remote chart that has no relation to parent chart. If subchart provides some sane defaults in a yaml file (say, for an environment), you cannot use this file in your parent chart, you have to copy-paste it. Imagine if you have hundreds or thousands of parent charts that all depend on one same subchart! (pretty common setup for microservices). It is incredibly disappointing that helm doesn't support this.